# Dividing two tuples

Tags: divisibility

Some brief context first. I am doing a Masters and while I am not a novice with numbers (stats is my strong suit) I am still learning math. I have tried to find the answer to the following question in textbooks, but I haven't found anything yet. If the question does not makes sense, please let me know.

Firstly, I have two 4-tuples: P = (a,b,x,d) and Q = (a,b,y,d). As can be seen, the only difference between the tuples are the x and y variables. For context: P is a prior estimation, where x is a target value. Q is the post-event actual, where y is the corresponding result.  (The other variables are common elements that effectively link the prior to the post-event).

In my research, I would like to divide P by Q, and be left with the variables x and y. Applying algebra, the common elements will cancel out. However, I am wanting to know if it is appropriate to divide two tuples in this way before I proceed further?

Thanks for helping

PS: There was no 'tuple' tag so hopefully I have got a suitable tag.

Comment: There is no general division for tuples, but if it satisfies your needs, you may *define* it that way (or introduce any other notation if you feel uncomfortable)

Comment: Thank you, Hagen.  I will take you suggestion and define it that way.